# ModuleNotFoundError: Can't set up proper module structure

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging, python-poetry

I've following structure where I want to access module from `data` package inside relative `scraping` package. There is common `betterhire` package, however I am getting following error. Please see attached pic of sturcture in VS Code

```
File "~/better-hire/src/betterhire/scraping/indeed.py", line 7, in <module>
    from betterhire.data.models import Company
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'
```

[image]

I expect that all submodules under `betterhire` package are cross importable. Please suggest the correct structure for Python projects that includes `src` folder `Poetry`.

Comment: Is the library installed? Which command(s) did you run? What is the full output?

Comment: @sinoroc It is a relative module in the parent folder

Comment: @OneCricketeer I do not understand what you mean. -- @Aren The project directory structure seems perfectly fine. The issue might be in the way you run the code. Let's assume you have an entry point in `src/betterhire/scraping/indeed.py`, then you should start this entry point like this: `python -m betterhire.scraping.indeed` (dots `.` instead of slashes `/` and no `.py`). Maybe this helps.

Comment: @sinoroc You asked if something is installed, when the error in the question is trying to load a local file, not any installed one

Comment: @OneCricketeer Ah... Because of the tilde `~` in the path in the error output? I see. -- I think we still need to know what command was run, what was the current working directory, and so on.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I've run it via `python src/betterhire/scraping/indeed.py`, because it's script. Can you elaborate why we should use `python -m betterhire.scraping.indeed` instead?

Comment: Did you try relative import? https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports

Comment: @ArenHovsepyan  See the answers on this post [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912).  If you run indeed.py as a script, then it not loaded as 
part of a package, and therefore it cannot do relative package imports, but relative imports will instead be directory based.  If you instead run it by using `python -m betterhire.scraping.indeed` it will be loaded as a module and it can then use the relative package imports as you are trying to do.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety, got it, so what if I want to run `indeed.py` as a script, but just include betterhire? Should it mandatorily be from pip installed packages?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, FYI I've tried `python -m`, but got following error

`python -m betterhire.scraping.craigslist
/Users/arenhovsepyan/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'betterhire.scraping.craigslist' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'betterhire')`. Also `betterhire` is part of my package so it's not pip installed

Comment: Ok, I think I got how it works. I need to be in `src` folder then run as a module via `python -m`. thanks!